# ember form input validation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using - https://offirgolan.github.io/ember-cp-validations/docs/classes/Custom.html

I would like to add bootstrap styling to my form fieldsets to say whether they are valid or invalid.

I can get it to add the bootstrap form class 'has-danger' if there is an error. But when the error is correct I cannot get it to change to 'has-success'.

below is a section of my form:
signup.hbs

```
<fieldset class="form-group row has-success {{if v-get model.isError 'has-danger'}}">
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label">
        Password
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" value=model.password}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3 input-error">
        {{v-get model 'password' 'message'}}
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

below is a snippet from my validation file:
validation.js

```
export const name = validator('presence', true)
export const password = [
  validator('presence', true),
  validator('length', {
    min: 4,
    max: 8,
    message: 'Please make sure the password is 4 - 8 characters long'
  }),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove static class `has-success`, then add fallback for `if` to `has-success` (when there's no error):

```
<fieldset class="form-group row {{if v-get model.isError 'has-danger' 'has-success'}}">
```

Comment: when i amend the line to the above i get the error: The inline form of the `if` and `unless` helpers expect two or three arguments, e.g. `{{if trialExpired 'Expired' expiryDate}}` or `{{unless isFirstLogin 'Welcome back!'}}`. im using ember version 2.5.1